# TextBox in GridView not holding its value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a gridview on a .NET forms application, and on postback, I am not seeing the values entered in the textbox within a gridview.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" DataKeyNames="ItemId" EnableViewState="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" Text="0" EnableViewState="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemId" /> 
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_OnClick" OnClientClick="javascript:return someClientStuff();" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gvItems.Rows)
    {                
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var itemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            var itemValue = ((row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtItem") as TextBox).Text;
        }
}
```

I am seeing itemId populated for each row, but itemValue is always empty string.

Been a while since I worked on a forms application, any help is appreciated!

Comment: looks like a scope issue here `var itemId and itemValue` where are you assigning them after the button click.. also do you have any `if(IsPostBack){}` check in your page load..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not assigning them anywhere yet--I am just debugging through it and noticed that they are empty for all rows.

Comment: it's a scope and or a Databind issue from the postback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the `DataBind` of the `GridView` is not in `if(!IsPostBack)`. Add this to the `Page_Load`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    gvItems.DataSource = soruceOftheGrid
    gvItems.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @Prabhu On every page load you are binding the grid again and again. Which will remove the current values, if they are not bind from the datasource. You can accept it if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

On the button click, try to store the values in the view state and within page load event, try to assign the viewstate back to the grid view as for each postback, page load event is called. Its good to assign the values back to grid view within page load, this will help you to retain the values you have entered.